# What is the optimal strategy for the launched site in Stack Egg?

Tags: stack-egg

Some of the sites seem to have a much better performance than others. In particular, during Stack Overflow's first round, I found that the stats always seemed quite low, with no traffic, and no seeming way to get out of the situation.

How can one best get through the launched phase, achieving the best performance?

Comment: Keep voting so that "reset" doesn't accidentally pass...

Comment: @badp [Open your browser console](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/8525) and enter `setInterval(function() { if (!$("#egg-actions").hasClass("egg-has-voted") && $("#egg-action-restartdecline button").click().length) console.log("Declined restart at "+new Date()); }, 10000);`

Comment: The optimal strategy is following badp's advice on one SE page and Bergi's for every other page ;)

Answer (score 37):

As far as I can tell, the following is the optimal strategy for the launched product. Every round, choose the top item from this list. If an item is 4 hearts, then go on to the next level.

1. If an item is red, it deserves prompt attention. It seems there is a 4 day grace period, after which a reset will be forced.
2. Raise the Questions via ask to 4 hearts.
3. Raise the Answers via answer to 4 hearts.
4. Raise the quality to 4 hearts via downvotes. Closed seems to be a waste, as it affects the top priority.
5. Raise the User via upvotes to 4 hearts.
6. Choose either ask or answer if everything is 4 hearts.

Why does this work?

1. If the question score is low, then the answer score will drop.
2. The traffic score increments if both quality and answers are high.
3. Traffic seems to be the biggest incrementer of the score.

Comment: Is there a consequence for the item being left red?

Comment: I haven't figured it out, but I suspect there is. It doesn't seem to happen right away, however.

Comment: How about traffic ?

Comment: Flags and Closing are both *very powerful* early on in the phase; I'm pretty sure starting off with a flag might be optimal. (And it reflects reality! Moderation is important early on before enough users have rep to moderate the site on their own!)

Comment: Unfortunately, we can't even get people to follow this even for our own site.

Comment: Traffic can't be directly optimized, but is optimized using this strategy.

Comment: For quality, which is better: closing or downvoting?

Comment: @Keen Since one of the bigger goals is keeping question score up, downvoting is normally better. Sacrificing users does less harm than sacrificing questions (...there's probably some cynical view of SE in there).

Comment: Since there's no traffic in public beta, I wonder whether this is the right strategy for that stage.

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz: After running through the game (mostly) by myself on the travel SE site, I actually think that Close is a **trap**. While Close will certainly grant a large amount of quality, it *always* seemed to need 2 entire turns in order for questions to recover the cost that Close required. In addition, there's no guarantee that quality won't decrease while you're busy asking questions for a couple of turns. It felt like I actually fell behind more than I would have if I had simply downvoted for 2 straight turns instead. And early in the phase, you're busy increasing questions anyway.

Comment: If items are left red for to long your site can get closed and then the ONLY option is to restart.

Comment: It appears that Users matters more than Quality score-wise, by watching Arqade's scores for a couple runs. We might be better off with upvotes and downvotes in reverse order in public beta to take advantage of the lack of a traffic stat.

Comment: @Sconibulus: That info would probably be better in a question that didn't focus on the launched stage of the site. Having said that, you might have something there. Cross validated currently has the lowest average of 252 days (based on only 1 win).

Comment: Not sure whether this strategy works well in the end game, it seems to continously swing between quality and questions. Any tips on that? Or is it just hard work?

Comment: That's the idea. Swinging between just quality and questions, while answers and users are more self sufficient. Otherwise you're playing whack-a-mole with all 4 in heavy play.

Comment: With max traffic, once quality starts dropping, it drops VERY fast until you downvote.  I'm thinking that makes it optimal to prioritize quality over everything else once traffic is maxed.  (But only with downvotes - it isn't worth spending the questions for closing.)

Comment: It only seems to drop if quality is below 2 hearts for very long. I think answers would have a similar effect.

Comment: It seems answers/ quality should be equally kept above 2, I'm not sure if a difference in priorities matters.

Comment: This "focus one stat at a time" strategy lets decay effects get large.  It's better to deliberately avoid boosting the same stat twice in a row.

Comment: Given optimal voting, what would be the lowest number of day achievable ?

Comment: Following the logic of blogs and many news based sites, it would be more sensible that Users increases Traffic more than Quality ;)

Answer (score 2):

It's generally optimal to alternate between stats, rather than boosting the same stat twice in a row.  Boosting a stat clears all of its accumulated decay, so it's better to let it accumulate a little decay before boosting it again.  Another effect of the decay system is that it's optimal to let a stat stay in the red for a few days before you do anything about it (unless you have nothing else to be doing), but that comes into play much less often.

I realize the cycles I describe below will be very difficult to follow in a group game, so here are some general guidelines:

1. Keep track of the invisible "decay" stat.  It increments by 1 for each stat each day, but resets to -2 when you actively increase a stat.  (Also, Downvote increases the decay of Users by 2, and every 2 Traffic hearts increases the decay of Quality by 1 per day.)  If a stat's Decay reaches +2, that stat loses a heart and the decay resets to 0.  Prefer to increase stats that have their decay at +1 and are also missing a heart.  Stats that are at 0 can be left alone for a few days, since they can't go any lower (and all their accumulated decay will go away when you increase them).  Just don't let their decay reach +8.
2. When decay points are equal, prioritize Questions first, then Answers.  In the Public beta round, prioritize users third; in the Graduated round, prioritize Quality third.

**In the first round (Private Beta)**, loop through these actions:

1. Ask
2. Answer

**In the second round (Public Beta)**, first loop through these actions until Answers is maxed, pausing to boost any stat that turns red:

1. Ask
2. Answer

Then loop through these actions:

1. Answer
2. Ask
3. Upvote
4. Downvote
5. Upvote

**In the third round (Graduated)**, first loop through these actions until Answers is maxed, pausing to boost any stat that turns red:

1. Ask
2. Answer

Then loop through these actions until Traffic reaches 3:

1. Ask
2. Downvote
3. Upvote
4. Answer
5. Downvote

Once Traffic reaches 3 hearts, loop through these actions until you win the internet:

1. Downvote
2. Ask
3. Downvote
4. Answer

(Once Traffic is maxed, Users will take care of itself.)

Comment: But using a flag could lead to a lower leaderboard rank...

Comment: @Gerret Does it?  I wasn't aware of that.  Do you know what effect it has, exactly?

Comment: The FAQ in the StackEgg game says: `[...]however, each flag that was left when winning the internet gives a bonus worth ten days in this calculation[...]`.

Comment: @Gerret Since using a flag could easily save 5 days, and win count is more important than day count, I'm not sure whether flag use is optimal or not.  But I'll remove the recommendations to use flags.

Answer (score 0):

In priority:

1. Don't restart unless [necessary](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/212042/at-what-point-would-a-site-be-better-to-restart-than-to-continue-on?rq=1)
2. Don't close
3. Only upvote when users is red

Comment: Note that in the public beta part of the game, upvoting is actually a good move.