# How do we win the internet?

Tags: stack-egg

In StackEgg there's this fairly ambiguous "progress toward winning the internet" bar.  So far no action has made a noticeable affect on it, and it doesn't appear to mention it in the FAQ.

Which aspects of the site most influence winning the internet?  What are the requisites for doing so?

Comment: Not sure if I should Close this as a dup of [What is the Optimal Strategy for a Launched Site in Stack Egg](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/211949/what-is-the-optimal-strategy-for-the-launched-site-in-stack-egg)

Comment: Fastest way, do it alone on a low traffic site.

Comment: @Powerlord That question talks about increasing the individual stats, I'm asking more of which of those stats (if any, and if not what) affects internet-winning progress.

Comment: Quality and user seems to matter less than Questions and Answer... from experience.

Comment: Quality matters because it affects traffic. See the questionable duplicate question.

Comment: I disagree that this is a duplicate, the other question is asking about strategy, this question is asking how the game works. How a game works and the best strategy to win it are two separate concerns.