# At what point would a site be better to restart than to continue on?

Tags: stack-egg

Murgatroid99 [made a comment](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/20849460#20849460) on how in all cases it is never worth restarting, and that trudging forward is the best option in any scenario.

> @Wipqozn not really. It's never faster to start a new run than to
>   continue one

Is that really true? Is there a point where it would be far more valuable to start over at square 1 as opposed to continuing on with low scores in everything else?

Comment: This probably depends on what your goal is. If you want the max number of wins during the event, I could see that. If you're trying to win the internet in the least number of days, there's plenty of scenarios where restarting would be beneficial.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are **some** situations in which restarting is better than continuing on.

As an extreme example, if people have <kbd>Nothing</kbd>'d away a few days and absolutely no progress on the egg has been made, then it is worth restarting.

From what I understand though, average days (which restart is used to decrease) is only used to tie-break **after** the rankings are sorted by wins.

This means that you should only ever restart if it's not going to affect the total times you win by the end of the competition, even if not restarting means drastically increasing your average days to win.