# Is there a random element to the Stack Egg game?

Tags: stack-egg

Is there some element of randomness to the Stack Egg game? If so, what is it? If not, is it then possible to determine the exact effects of each action and therefore construct an optimal path to minimize score?

Comment: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/211949/what-is-the-optimal-strategy-for-the-launched-site-in-stack-egg

Comment: I'm more focused on the randomness to the game. Yes I can follow that strategy to have a "good" game, but will it work out exactly the same every time? Or will that just keep us moving in the general direction of victory?

Comment: I would say that "other users" are the random element

Comment: If we convince everyone to use the same strategy or go on an empty SE, is there a perfect game then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [code source](https://github.com/StackExchange/stackegg) is now available and no random numbers were used in it. There exists an optimal path as the game is not complex at all. Fun regardless.